# Copying the youtube url

Tags: applications, 4.4-kitkat, youtube

Is there a way I could simply copy the url of a youtube video to the clipboard in android 4?

I discovered that it is possible if you install the Google drive app (13.5MB) which adds the option "Copy to clipboard" under the sharing options, but this seems a waste of space for what should be a simple functionality.

Comment: Assuming that it's impossible to do this natively (no "Copy to clipboard" function), is it okay to install similar app that's much smaller than Google Drive app?

Comment: I agree with Andrew, we have to use 3rd party app. Clipper - Clipboard Manager is less than 3 MB. You can also try Pocket/Google Keep.

Comment: @Andrew T.:Thanks for the suggestion. I thought there would be an xposed module or something for such a thing, but I was wrong.

Comment: Are you talking about copying the video url from within the YouTube app itself?  If so, there's a workaround.

Comment: You tag 4.4-kitkat, and I'm with the Nexus 4 on 4.4.4 kitkat and I have "Copy to clipboard" in the "Share" button. In Chrome when i share the page and in the YouTube app when I share the video. I share it with Google Keep and from the Chrome it's save (only) the url, and within the YouTube app it's save the title and the url.

Comment: Yes, I suppose the Gapps package includes the Google Drive app, which has that option. Forgot to mention I'm on root and minimal Gapps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several options out there, but nothing native.  Share to Clipboard by Alexey Lyubeznov is a much smaller app than Google Drive - only 11 kb - and doesn't require any special permissions. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sharetoclipboard

Comment: Perfect! By the looks of it (icon), this app is also used in the Google Drive app?

Comment: It's slightly different, but close. I doubt it's the same code, but it has the same result.